# Value is a floating point number python 3

Tags: python

This is a Python challenge in my computing class. My teacher can't figure out the answer and I'm the furthest in the class so no one else knows what to do. I've tried everything I can think of.

```
Write a program that checks that the value entered is a floating point number.
Check the program works by entering an integer to see if an error is raised. 
If a float is entered it should output the number.
```

This has to be done in Python 3.4.3

```
num=input("Enter a number")
if num = float:
  print("This is a float")
else:
  print("This is not a float")
```

I can't figure out how to make it so the input is isn't instantly set to a float.

Comment: Please do show us what you've tried though - it makes it easier to answer the question appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle this through a few exceptions, relying on the fact that a failed conversion raises a `ValueError`:

```
input_value = input("> ")
try:
    int_value = int(input_value)
    print("invalid input: value was an int!")
except ValueError:
    try:
        float_value = float(input_value)
        print(float_value)  # just echo
    except ValueError as e:
        print("invalid input: ", " ".join(e.args))
```

(Python 3 inside)

Comment: This is more complex than what OP needs, he just wants to know if it's float (no need to check for int), but the idea is perfect